# CherryPy 3.6 - reading Multipart Post http request

Tags: http, post, request, cherrypy, multipart

I coded a java client that sends a string of meta information and a byte array through a multipart post http request to my server running cherrypy 3.6.

I need to extract both values and I coded this in python3 on the server side to find out how to manipulate the result as I can't find any relevant documentation over internet that explains how to read this html part

```
def controller(self, meta, data):

        print("meta", meta)
        print("data", type(data))
```

outputs :

```
my meta information
<class 'cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part'>
```

**Note :** *the data part contains raw binary data.*

How can I read the http part content into a buffer or output it to a disk file ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. 
I'v already read this doc but unfortunately methods read-into_file and make_file, read ... it doesn't work for me. for example when trying to read a zip file sent form my java client :

Assuming **data** is the Http post parameter

**make_file()**

```
fp = data.make_file()
print("fp type", type(fp)) # _io.BufferedRandom
zipFile =  fp.read()
```

outputs:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

line 651, in read_lines_to_boundary raise EOFError("Illegal end of multipart body.")EOFError: Illegal end of multipart body.

**read_into_file()**

```
    file = data.read_into_file()
    print("file type", type(file))
    zipFile =  io.BytesIO(file.read())
    # zipFile =  file.read() # => raises same error
```

outputs:

```
line 651, in read_lines_to_boundary raise EOFError("Illegal end of multipart body.")EOFError: Illegal end of multipart body.
```

I don't understand what happens ...

Actually "data" is not a file like object but a cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part one. It holds a "file" file an _io.BufferedRandom class property.

Its read() method returns the whole body content in a binary form (bytes).

**so to end up the straightforward solution is :**

```
class BinReceiver(object):

    def index(self, data):

        zipFile =  io.BytesIO(data.file.read())
        path = "/tmp/data.zip"
        fp = open(path)
        fp.write(zipFile, 'wb')
        fp.close()

        print("saved data into", path, "size", len(zipFile))

    index.exposed = True
```

and this works fine ...

fyi : I'm running python3.2

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `data` is a file-like object which you can call `.read` on. In addition CherryPy provides a method `read_into_file`.

See the full documentation by typing `help(cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part)` in your REPL.

```
class Part(Entity)
 |  A MIME part entity, part of a multipart entity.
 |  
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Part
 |      Entity
 |      __builtin__.object
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, fp, headers, boundary)
 |  
 |  default_proc(self)
 |      Called if a more-specific processor is not found for the
 |      ``Content-Type``.
 |  
 |  read_into_file(self, fp_out=None)
 |      Read the request body into fp_out (or make_file() if None).
 |      
 |      Return fp_out.
 |  
 |  read_lines_to_boundary(self, fp_out=None)
 |      Read bytes from self.fp and return or write them to a file.
 |      
 |      If the 'fp_out' argument is None (the default), all bytes read are
 |      returned in a single byte string.
 |      
 |      If the 'fp_out' argument is not None, it must be a file-like
 |      object that supports the 'write' method; all bytes read will be
 |      written to the fp, and that fp is returned.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Class methods defined here:
 |  
 |  from_fp(cls, fp, boundary) from __builtin__.type
 |  
 |  read_headers(cls, fp) from __builtin__.type
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  attempt_charsets = ['us-ascii', 'utf-8']
 |  
 |  boundary = None
 |  
 |  default_content_type = 'text/plain'
 |  
 |  maxrambytes = 1000
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from Entity:
 |  
 |  __iter__(self)
 |  
 |  __next__(self)
 |  
 |  fullvalue(self)
 |      Return this entity as a string, whether stored in a file or not.
 |  
 |  make_file(self)
 |      Return a file-like object into which the request body will be read.
 |      
 |      By default, this will return a TemporaryFile. Override as needed.
 |      See also :attr:`cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part.maxrambytes`.
 |  
 |  next(self)
 |  
 |  process(self)
 |      Execute the best-match processor for the given media type.
 |  
 |  read(self, size=None, fp_out=None)
 |  
 |  readline(self, size=None)
 |  
 |  readlines(self, sizehint=None)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors inherited from Entity:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  type
 |      A deprecated alias for :attr:`content_type<cherrypy._cpreqbody.Entity.content_type>`.
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes inherited from Entity:
 |  
 |  charset = None
 |  
 |  content_type = None
 |  
 |  filename = None
 |  
 |  fp = None
 |  
 |  headers = None
 |  
 |  length = None
 |  
 |  name = None
 |  
 |  params = None
 |  
 |  part_class = <class 'cherrypy._cpreqbody.Part'>
 |      A MIME part entity, part of a multipart entity.
 |  
 |  parts = None
 |  
 |  processors = {'application/x-www-form-urlencoded': <function process_u...
```